# Why is the structure of 3, 4-Dimethylhexane given as follows?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Question: name the IUPAC name of the following structure:

[image: The compound]

And here's what I could come up with is this: we start from the first carbon atom from the extreme left and end with the 2nd substitute while moving right (considering the first C atom at the extreme left to be in 1st position). After that, we have the first substituent in the 2nd position and we get `2 ethyl` and then we have '3 methyl' and the root will be `pentane`. So, we get `2-ethyl, 2-methyl pentane`.

However, here's the answer given in my book `3, 4-Dimethylhexane`. Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you started at the wrong atom. You should start on the ethyl group since it will give you a longer chain.